# Security concerns for posting live site code on GitHub public repo

Tags: django, github, dokku

First, I am trying to get my first software engineering job and have limited "completed" projects including my resume site (built in Django). I currently self host on my a dokku home server and I want to put the code for the few sites I do have live to GitHub for sharing with potential employers. I've mostly kept my sites in private repos but with now wanting to make them public, I'm having security concerns.

A few security precautions I have taken already:

- Change my admin login route (if posting code that route is made public)
- Removed all domain specific items (With resume site, that will
  be public)
- All keys for apis are in ENV files that are not shared

Things I'm considering doing:

- At minimum migrating my sites to public hosting because I don't think I monitor my security well enough.
- Have 2 different repos for each site, private and public. I'd hate to do it, because of complicating things in my already complicated career change, but I could see the benefits.

What are some security concerns I didn't think of or how do people keep public repos for live sites?

Comment: You can take a look at the [documentation to deploy a Django app on Google](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine). It discusses what items to keep secret (and are thus secrets in the GAE). You do not need to use GAE here, but the documentation can be used to understand what parts should remain private.

Comment: Not django-specific, but even if you have removed sensitive information from your current version, ensure that you don't make public older commits containing API keys, passwords, personal data or anything else you would like to keep private.

Comment: @pereic Do you know of any easy way to find information buried in historic commits? I'm thinking early on in development I may have committed somethings that were not ideal , but searching files that have several commits over the years seems daunting. Might be worth loosing all the history and starting from scratch.